# Task label with TikZ doesn't work anymore

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, tasks

Skillmon's solution proposed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/418893/101651) doesn't work anymore, with an up-to-date TeX distribution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tasks}

\newcommand*\Choice[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-5pt]
        \node[gray,inner sep=8pt,draw=gray!50,rounded corners] {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}}

  \newcounter{choicelabel}
\newcommand*\Choicelabel{%
  \refstepcounter{choicelabel}%
  \hskip1em\llap{\Choice{\Alph{choicelabel}}}}%

\everymath={\displaystyle}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\normalsize{\@setfontsize\normalsize{13.5pt}{1.5em}}
\normalsize  
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Question goes here.
\begin{tasks}[label=\Choicelabel](2)
    \task $\frac{9}{17}$
    \task $\frac{12}{17}$
    \task $\frac{13}{17}$
    \task $\frac{13}{17}$
    \task $\frac{8}{17}$
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

I get the error:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \csname\endcsname 
l.31 \end
         {tasks}
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.
```

Is it still possible to create a task label with Ti*k*Z?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The new version of `tasks` allows for setting the label formatting in the options of the environment. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tasks}

\newcommand*\Choice[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-5pt]
        \node[gray,inner sep=8pt,draw=gray!50,rounded corners] {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\everymath={\displaystyle}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\normalsize{\@setfontsize\normalsize{13.5pt}{1.5em}}
\normalsize  
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Question goes here.
\begin{tasks}[label-format=\Choice,label=\Alph*,label-width=26pt](2)
    \task $\frac{9}{17}$
    \task $\frac{12}{17}$
    \task $\frac{13}{17}$
    \task $\frac{13}{17}$
    \task $\frac{8}{17}$
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]